# hard caching with laravel

Tags: wordpress, laravel, caching

it is possible to easily cache values with laravel

https://scotch.io/tutorials/caching-in-laravel-with-speed-comparisons

but: the result (if you scroll down) is still very slow

i know that wordpress with W3 total cache can result in response times < 100 ms for cached pages ( see [here](http://www.wegweiser-freiwilligenarbeit.com/) for an example, e.g. check response times with web dev tools, i get often <50 ms)

does not something similar exist for laravel? is the guy from scotch.io doing a systematical mistake?

Comment: Which cache driver do you use?

Comment: @KorayKüpe i am actually referencing the results the guy was posting on his tests. He displayes results that are like 1500ms+ with all drivers, which is unsatisfying when compared to 50ms?

Answer (score 2):

Both caches are quite different. Using the Laravel cache, you cache small amounts of data, for example from the database, to use in your view.

The W3 cache plugin, however, will cache the content of entire pages and save this to a static file. When the page is revisited, this static file will be loaded instead of rendering everything again.

If you would like to do something like this I suggest you take a look at [Varnish HTTP cache](https://varnish-cache.org/).